# Road curves left

Tags: canada, road-signs

What's the difference between the following two [warning signs](https://www.alberta.ca/warning-signs.aspx) in Alberta, Canada? The first sign is called "Road curves left" and the second sign is called "Road turns left and right". Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where did you find these? Are they from the same country? They don't look so different.

Comment: so wait are you asking the difference in meaning, which is what you wrote, or the difference in the sign logo, which is a more curved elbow. We can agree that it's a ridiculously thin nuance, that a driver is unlikely to even detect. But then you already gave the answer.

Comment: One is a turn the other is a curve, isn't it clear from the descriptions?

Comment: @littleadv what's the difference between a road turning to the left and a road curving to the left?

Comment: @ChrisH you'll probably want to ask Alberta DMV, but usually turns are the ones where the direction changes significantly enough for the line of sight before the turn not to see what's after, while with curves you can still see the road after the curve before getting into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two signs are [WA-5-L](https://open.alberta.ca/dataset/d44b8e8c-f4c6-468d-898e-d0ba6c3bfa3a/resource/f825cb56-426d-4609-802d-b9ca01595995/download/wa-5-l.pdf) "**Left Reverse Curve**" and [WA-4-L](https://open.alberta.ca/dataset/d44b8e8c-f4c6-468d-898e-d0ba6c3bfa3a/resource/2e75245b-e16e-467c-8609-a7c1c7129b81/download/wa-4-l.pdf) "**Left Reverse Turn**".

**The difference between a curve and a turn is how much the road turns/curves, and how much you should slow down to go through the turn/curve**, i.e. the same different which exists between "turn right" and "curve right" ([full list here](https://open.alberta.ca/dataset/d44b8e8c-f4c6-468d-898e-d0ba6c3bfa3a/resource/b2747f38-9b9b-49d7-b88e-73beadb3e6a5/download/wa-phy-cond.pdf)).

In both cases, the road first turns/curves left, then turns/curves right. The opposite signs (WA-5-R and WA-4-R) also exist.

If there are more than 2 curves, then [WA-6-L](https://open.alberta.ca/dataset/d44b8e8c-f4c6-468d-898e-d0ba6c3bfa3a/resource/ea45bae9-7b34-4684-ae5a-28035ffbe46b/download/wa-6-l.pdf) "Left Winding Road" is used (if the first turn is to the left, otherwise WA-6-R).

Haven't found the equivalent for Alberta, but [BC have a "Manual of
Standard Traffic Signs & Pavement Markings"](https://www.atstraffic.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/MoST_PM.pdf) which gives (pages 69 to 72) the procedure to determine the max advisory speed, and from that and the max legal speed, the type of sign which should be used (turn or curve).

Comment: Thank you all for your detailed explanations! Happy holidays!

Answer (score 7):

For drivers, the difference is that turns usually are more difficult to manoeuvre than curves and may require a greater attention and a lower speed.

For the technical differences, this is explained in the guidelines from Alberta Transportation: [TURN AND CURVE SIGNS](https://open.alberta.ca/dataset/9ca0c2c4-6f24-4c53-ab0c-93b0672a59e1/resource/a9a13a21-a48a-4505-99f2-ee48b45e3f0b/download/trans-turn-and-curve-signs-2006-12.pdf), [REVERSE TURN
AND REVERSE CURVE SIGNS](https://open.alberta.ca/dataset/73f37e0b-6049-4584-955f-bb447ae92254/resource/ac25ab4f-913c-429f-9408-0d8e3e687d9d/download/trans-reverse-turn-and-reverse-curve-signs-2006-12.pdf). The difference between a turn, sharp curve and curve is outlined in the table  provided in the first document, based on the difference between recommended safe speed and the normal speed limit on the road.

[image: Table on the criteria for selecting the correct warning signs: turn, sharp curve, or curve]

Note that these guidelines are recommendations and the provincial or local infrastructure department may decide to adopt a sign different from the guideline recommendation if needed by the circumstances (e.g. using reverse turn signs on a reverse curve where accidents are more frequent).

Answer (score -2):

The page has an error.

Both of these signs mean a left curve **followed by a right curve**, also called an S-curve.   That also exists in a mirror-image for a right then left.

This is distinct from "winding road" which means a whole ton of curves, sequence not specified, so you could have that exact sign with a first curve to the *left*.

As others say in answers, the different styles of sign reflect **different sharpness of the curves** ahead.  They use the words "Curves" and "Turns" to indicate the relative sharpness and the necessity for you to adjust speed.

If you ask me that's too subtle, and where speed reduction is needed, a warning sign to that effect should be included.  I also don't consider that to be proper use of the word "turn".  A "turn" to me is a sharp 90, as at an intersection.

Comment: I don't think it is an error, even if the language could be much clearer; the learner's manual only shows one example (left or right; or left followed by right or right followed by left) for each type of sign.

Comment: @xngtng Based on the links in your answer, I believe there is in fact an error - the "road curves left" sign should be a mirror image of the "road curves right" sign as shown in your first link. The image shown for "road curves left" is in fact the "reverse curve left" (i.e. left then right curve) sign, as shown in your second link.

Comment: The page has indeed mismatching labels and images, but there are actually separate (reverse) "turn" and "curve" signs, it's not just a difference in style.

Comment: @xngtng yeah, I'm seeing that. Edited.

Comment: @jcaron so I've come to understand.  I consider it a design flaw however; no driver has the time to notice what amount to differences in style.  Curves requiring reduction in speed need signs specifically saying that IMO. We do that in the USA.

Comment: All turn and sharp curve signs following the provincial guidelines in Alberta should have a recommended advisory speed panel in addition (although I've seen ones without).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica the rules I found for BC state in which cases an additional advisory speed panel should be added, basically anytime the advisory speed is 20 km/h or more less than the legal limit. It can also increase to additional “Slow” signs, flashing lights, etc.